# Finding the integral of $(x^2+4x)/\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can somebody explain me how to calculate this integral?

$$\int \frac{\left(x^2+4x\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}dx$$

Comment: Try Euler's first substitution:$$\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}=x+t$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle\frac{d(x^2+2x+2)}{dx}=2x+2,$

write $$x^2+4x=(x^2+2x+2)+(2x+2)-4$$

Use  $\#1,\#8$ of [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/integ11.html)

Comment: @amWhy, We have $$\int\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1^2}dx+\int\frac{d(x^2+2x+2)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}-4\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x+1=\tan\theta$, so $x=\tan\theta-1$, $dx=\sec^{2}\theta d\theta$, and $\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}=\sec\theta$.

Then $\displaystyle\int\frac{x^2+4x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}dx=\int\frac{(\tan\theta-1)^2+4(\tan\theta-1)}{\sec\theta}\sec^{2}\theta d\theta$

$\displaystyle=\int(\tan^{2}\theta+2\tan\theta-3)\sec\theta d\theta=\int(\sec^{2}\theta-1+2\tan\theta-3)\sec\theta d\theta$

$=\displaystyle\int(\sec^{3}\theta-4\sec\theta+2\sec\theta\tan\theta)\; d\theta$

$=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}(\sec\theta\tan\theta+\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|)-4\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+2\sec\theta+C$

$=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}-\frac{7}{2}\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+x+1\right)+2\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+C$.